# Linq to SQL Join IQueryable Set Certain Property

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, iqueryable

Is this possible?

Let's say I had a simple IQueryable join like below:

```
            var x = from t1 in Repo.GetThing1()
                    join t2 in Repo.GetThing2() on t1.Key equals t2.Key
                    select t1).ToList();
```

But let's there is a field on t1 that I want to set with t2.  However I don't want to re-map all the fields from t1, I just want the ability to map that particular field in t1 from t2...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure:

```
var query = from t1 in Repo.GetThing1()
            join t2 in Repo.GetThing2() on t1.Key equals t2.Key
            select new { Existing = t1, NewValue = t2.SomeField };

var list = query.ToList();

foreach (var pair in list)
{
    pair.Existing.SomeField = pair.NewValue;
}
```

(Then you can do whatever you want, of course.)